# Ultra slow speed while transfer files between PC and Samsung S5

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb, file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-5, mtp

I just got my new Samsung Galaxy S5, original ROM with version 4.4.2. It uses a new Toshiba 64GB speed U3 micro SD card.

When I transfer my WhatsApp folder from PC to GS5, it took me more than 24 hours!!!

The WhatsApp folder has about 3GB in size, and thousands of received/sent images.

At the first time, I transfer them from PC to the (fast) SD card in the phone. It really took me more than 24 hours. At the second time, I tried transfer them from PC to the phone internal memory. It seems to be a little bit faster. I did not wait it to complete. But I assume it will take 20+ hours also.

When I use the file manager in GS5 to copy the entire 3GB folder from SD card to phone internal, it takes only 5 minutes or less. (It's a U3 card afterall)

I did a small test. I transfer only the database files from PC to the SD card (in the phone). There are 7 files, in total 1 GB in size. It takes only 1 minute.

So my guess is, **the transfer speed will be ultra slow when it contains many small files**.

- The same issue happens in different fast computers.
- I used the original USB cable, and tried on other short and average quality cables.
- I prefer not to pull my SD card out every time. Even if i do, transfer from PC to phone also have the ultra slow speed issue.
- I know there are threads suggesting to transfer file by other methods. But my concern is: **Why is it so unreasonable slow?** And I prefer using the USB method.

Is my phone a defect?

Comment: Are you using USB 2.0 or USB 3.0? As the answer below indicates it will be slow no matter what because of the way MTP is however speeds are suppose to be better with a USB 3.0 cable

Comment: I suppose that is a 3.0 (but not 100% sure). However even if it is a 2.0 it still should not be that terribly slow

Comment: IF your using the original cable then it is most likely a USB 2.0, for some reason USB 3.0 isn't supplied with the phone.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for your suggestion. I will find an USB 3.0 cable and try again. :)

Comment: While @midnite has given a perfect explanation of the problem. To solve this, you should enable usb debugging in your android and then the transfer rates are as expected from usb.

Comment: I had this problem too in my OPO. It iss very frustrating when you find that your time is getting killed by such stupid things. Ultimately, I found some solutions and the best ones are listed [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/106323#106323). You may try it sometime.

Comment: oh yeah big help USB 3.0 to go from painfully slow to just under a snail's pace and still just as painfull, again I say, useless

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia is our friend, again. :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol#Drawbacks

Quote:

MTP allows **no parallelism**, unlike USB mass storage or NAS. MTP has been built to **only allow a single operation at a time** (for example, read, write or delete operation), while no other operation can be executed until the previous operation is complete.

By design, MTP devices (like PTP devices) are not treated as a traditional removable drive. The actual file system is implemented by the device, and not by the computer's operating system. This also means that **file system recovery tools on the computer will be of no use**. In addition, most other programs on the computer will not recognise the MTP device, limiting the user to software from the device manufacturer or other MTP specific programs.

**When opening a file, the user must wait until the file is copied to the host computer/device before it can be viewed**; the file remains on the host computer's storage after viewing and after removal of the device.

Devices that are limited to MTP transfers do not allow or support instant access or multitasking.

The MTP and PTP standards do not support direct modification of objects. **Modified objects must be copied out of the device and reuploaded in their entirety, which can take a long time for large objects.** Google's MTP implementation in Android includes extensions to deal with this limitation; however, these extensions must be supported by the host operating system, and are not available by default. **This blocks the direct creation of files on the device from the host computer; files must be first created on the host computer and then copied over.**

...

Most MTP-compatible devices **are not assigned drive letters**; instead, they appear as "devices" in applications such as Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution for that. first creat a zip file of the images or whatever you want to copy then paste that zip file to your phone and then unzip the files to the respective folders. Use xplore file manager for that which is best file manager which i m using since last more than 10 years

Comment: one more thing. before copying it to the phone just change the extention from .zip to something else anything unusaul which cant be recognized by system then copy that file. after successfull copying change extenstion back to .zip.

Comment: @jayesh Your last comment seems to be a CRITICAL step in the supposed solution. Why can it not be EDITED into the defacto answer? Comments are considered transitory and can be deleted at any time. The original post can contain this supposed CRITICAL step permanently.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Compared to other forums, the structure of this site is basically questions and answers, with additional comments. You can always [edit] your post to expand and add more detail, while comments are generally used only for additional info. Consider taking a quick [tour] to understand more how this site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found someone with the same issue as the OP, so don't worry your phone is not defective.

I would like to first add a few thoughts in response to the answer above. While it may be correct that MTP is a slow protocol, this speed reduction is exclusive to the WhatsApp folder transfer only. Any other folder containing equal size transfers in minutes. So there has to be something in the nature of the WhatsApp folder itself, or its structure/specific files that are causing the slowdown.

This brings me to my solution to the problem, I personally use the [SuperBeam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam) app both on the phone and PC. You do need the pro key for $1, this reduces the 24+ hour transfer to like an hour, so this helps greatly. I would like to point out that this takes much longer than any other folder of the same size.

Comment: It's the humungous no. of small files that's the issue. (I'll ping the technical reason for this issue later.) Any other folder with similar files will give the pain as well. It's not about just Whatsapp folder. Try copying or deleting such folder from partition to partition in a good spec PC, you'll feel the misery again.

Answer (score 0):

Using "[MTP alternative USB Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clearevo.mtp_alternative) " app on your android phone along Dolphin file manager on Linux distro you can improve the file transfer rate.

Steps:
On phone:

1. Open MTP alternative USB Drive app on android phone and start USB tethering and select OS ( Ubuntu )

On PC:

2. Open dolphin file manager and go to "Network"
3. Click on "Add network folder"
   4.Select the type of network folder "webdav"
   5.Enter the network information (Name - any name you prefer for that folder)
4. leave username blank
5. Enter the IP (192.168.42.129) , that shown in your MTP android app.
6. configure port as 8081.
7. Give folder name "sdcard" for internal accessing memory or "storage" for accessing external memory card.
8. Save and connect.

Now you will be able to access your phones memory with ease.

Note : you can watch my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs6woLcV3OA) at YouTube if you have difficulty following the aforementioned instructions.