# How can large amounts of files be transferred to Linux via MTP?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, mtp, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I'm trying to copy all of my pictures from my Samsung Galaxy S9+ to my laptop (running Linux Mint). I can transfer a few files at a time no problem, but I have amassed 1000's of files in my pictures folder.

When attempting to copy the folder across using the file manager, the operation stalls and then fails every time. I would prefer to do it via the terminal, but since Samsung phones use mtp to transfer files, I have no idea what commands to use.

Comment: I had the same issue while transferring large number of files. I came up with a solution which I have mentioned in an another answer here: [Ultra slow speed while transfer files between PC and Samsung S5](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/237117/350426).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MTP is crap for that task – OK for a few files in "small folders", but stalling for folders with many files in, or copying many files, or trying things in parallel.

As you use Linux, [ADB](/tags/adb/info) would be a great alternative. I use that with [adbfs-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless), which allows mounting the device locally on your computer and works like a charm (I'm using it for years, so I can confirm it works at least up to Oreo).

First, to get ADB running, you can check with [How do I get my device detected by ADB on Linux?](/q/144966/16575). ADB binaries are shipped in the repositories of many distributions by a name like `android-tools-adb` so you can easily install them; alternatively take a look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](/q/42474/16575) for an even smaller footprint.

Installation of `adbfs` is quite straight-forward if you have the essential build tools already installed on your system: according to the readme, next to `build-essential` you'll need `libfuse-dev` and `pkg-config` available on your system. The `git` package is only needed if you want to clone the Github repository (alternatively, you can simply download the code as ZIP). `cd` to the directory you've cloned/unpacked the code to, and run `make`. When that's done, copy the `adbfs` binary to your path (e.g. into `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin` if you've set that up), so you don't need to specify the full path with each call – and you are ready to use it.

Finally, create a mount-point (an empty directory where your device's file system shall appear, say `mnt` in your home directory), and mount it with `adbfs ~/mnt` – et voila, your copy party can begin; from the terminal or graphically is up to you. When done, use `fusermount -u ~/mnt` to unmount your device again.

As a little bonus for you: should you sometimes have multiple devices attached at the same time, you'll need to set the `ANDROID_SERIAL` environment variable to tell `adbfs` which device to connect to. Here's a little script making that easier for you:

```
        case "$(adb devices|grep -v "devices"|grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$'|wc -l)" in
          0) echo "Nothing to mount (no device attached)" ;;
          1) export ANDROID_SERIAL=$(adb devices|grep -v "devices"|grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$'|awk '{print $1'})
             adbfs /mnt/droid
             ;;
          *) devices=''
             tmpfile=$(tempfile)
             adb devices -l|grep -v "devices"|grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' > $tmpfile
             while IFS='\n' read i
             do
               test="$(echo $i | awk '{print $2}')"
               if [ "$test" = "device" ]; then
                 devices="$devices $(echo $i | awk '{print $1}')"
                 devices="$devices \"$(echo $i | awk '{print $5}')\""
               fi
             done < "$tmpfile"
             rm -f -- "$tmpfile"
             serial=$(whiptail --clear --menu 'Multiple devices found, make your choice:' 0 0 0 $devices 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
             export ANDROID_SERIAL=$serial
             adbfs /mnt/droid
        esac
```

If you wonder about the indention: it's a snippet out of my Midnight-Commander (`mc`) menu. You can insert it there, preceding it by

```
= t d
+f ^mnt$
m       Mount Droid
```

So whenever your mount point is highlighted by the cursor, pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> will make that menu item available and you can easily mount your device. For unmounting, here's the second menu item:

```
+f ^mnt$
u       uMount Droid
        fusermount -u /mnt/droid
```

`^mnt$` is the name of the mount-point you've created – so if you used a different name, you need to adjust this as well.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! Mounting the phone is a much better solution.

Comment: Definitely. Makes you completely free to chose the copy software you prefer – be it command-line `cp`/`rsync` or a graphical file manager. You could even go a step further and integrate that with a `udev` rule – so whenever that device is attached, its storage would be mounted automatically. I haven't done that as I'm unsure how to handle the `umount` then, which must be done before unplug and thus would be hard to automate ;)